# Excel use cell value as range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file. There is a changable row quantity for column A for every time and that's why I need to make dynamic formula. For example;

I want to write "=LEN(B1)" formula on B1. And when make double click on right down corner of the cell, it's going to the end of until when column A values ends. That's why, before all this process, I wrote "=COUNT(A:A)" on cell C1.

In my VBA, I want to write;

```
Dim TEMP As String
TEMP = Range("C1").Value
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="=+LEN(RC[-1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:TEMP")
```

But there is something wrong in this process. As a result, I just want to use a cell value in my VBA as a range or string or number.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: **`=LEN(B1)` formula on `B1`** gives you a circular reference!

Comment: No it didn't. What do you mean?

Comment: @EEM - His code and his explanation say two different things. If you look at the code, it makes more sense ... OP seems to want to write **=Len(A1)** on cell B1.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman I noticed that, just tried to bring that to OP's attention, sometimes refusal to think is overwhelming...

Comment: Hello @PoyrazÖzer, is it you want to write VBA code that can fill down the formula in B1 over column B depending on how many rows there is in column A that have data? is this your objective of writing the VBA code ?

Comment: Hello @KSSheon I just want to write on B1 cell =LEN(A1), B2 cell =LEN(A2), B3 cell =LEN(A3) and goes on... And my A column could have different rows on my every query. That's why I have to make it dynamically for every row quantity.

Comment: @PoyrazÖzer, The line that didn't work should be `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:TEMP")`. It should be `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:" & TEMP)` because `TEMP` is a variable you declared. Besides you don't need to do the row counting in cell C1. You can do it in VBA i.e. `TEMP = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A:A"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two notes:

1. It's best practice to always qualify your objects (workbooks, worksheets, ranges, etc.) beforehand
2. When you use `R1C1` notation, you can just write the formula directly to the range (with no need for `AutoFill` or `FillDown`)

Try this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'edit for your sheet name
Dim lRow as Long
lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlup).Row
ws.Range("B1:B" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=Len(RC[-1])"
```

And just as a side note worth mentioning  the way you wrote `Range("B1:TEMP")` is not proper syntax. Correct syntax would be `Range("B1:B" & TEMP)`, which, of course, would only work if `TEMP` was indeed a numerical value :)

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work me. Actually maybe my explanation is wrong or missing.
I had sometimes 10 rows sometimes 15 rows in my column A. And I want to write length of each A column cell to B1 cell. And that's why firstly I wrote how many rows I had in column A with COUNT formula to use this value as my range end.
By the way, formula didn't work or I couldn't progress it.

Comment: so you want to return 10 or 15 (or whatever the number is) Length values into one cell (B1)? Or can you  provide a screenshot with your data and what you want your end result to be?

Comment: No no. It's just an example. It could be 100, or 1.000. I mean whatever the number is.

Comment: @PoyrazÖzer - you still didn't answer my question. Do you want to return the length of each cell in column A in the corresponding row in column B? If yes, then why doesn't the code above **not** work for you? If not, please update your OP with a screenshot of your data and expected result.

Comment: Yes, B1=LEN(A1), B2=LEN(A2), B3=LEN(A3)... and goes on. I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: @PoyrazÖzer - This code is very basic and will do just as you ask. However, I cannot help you get over your issues unless you can tell what did not work you. What results did you get when you ran the code? Also, did you make sure the correct sheet is referenced in the code?

Comment: please not that, from my A1 to A17, it's all writing "128". My all B column is blank. On my C1 cell is =COUNT(A:A). My sheet name is Sheet1.
And in my VBA, it's;
#Sub CountFormulaAs()#
#Dim ws As Worksheet#
#Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")#
#Dim lRow As Long#
#lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row#
#ws.Range("B1:B" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=Len(RC[-1])"#
#End Sub#
When I ran VBA, there is no changing on my sheet and there is no error. Is it clear for now?

Comment: @PoyrazÖzer - So, when you run the VBA you literally have nothing in column B at all? And `Range(A1:A17)` and `C1`  are left as is? I am very confused... I think there is some detail which you are not expressing (maybe because you don't know), because this code works great for me (tested multiple times and ways) and is most basic vba. How are you running the code? Did you step through it line-by-line to see what happens?